# Pycryptodome AES_OCB encryption nonce how to add nonce?

Tags: python

So I have been making an encryption and decryption program and I wanted to use AES with OCB mode only problem is I have no idea how you get "nonce" working and my program doesn't want to accept a random number or similar it just tells me:

"Nonce must be at most 15 bytes long"

My full code:

```
import base64
import hashlib
from Crypto import Random
from Crypto.Cipher import AES

BS = 16
pad = lambda s: s + (BS - len(s) %BS) * chr(BS - len(s) %BS)
unpad = lambda s : s[0:-s[-1]]

class AESCipher:

    def __init__(self, key):
        self.key = hashlib.sha256(key.encode('utf-8')).digest()

    def encrypt(self, raw):
        raw = pad(raw)
        iv = Random.new().read(AES.block_size)
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return base64.b64encode( iv + cipher.encrypt(raw.encode('utf8')))

    def decrypt(self, encoded):
        encoded = base64.b64decode(encoded)
        iv = encoded[:16]
        cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_CBC, iv)
        return unpad(cipher.decrypt(encoded[16:]))


cipher = AESCipher('mysecretpassword')
encrypted = cipher.encrypt('Secret Message A')
decrypted = cipher.decrypt(encrypted)
print(encrypted)
print(decrypted)
```

So at the moment I am using AES CBC mode but since switching to OCB should only add nonce as extra parameter I should only need that.

**So my question here is basically: how do I add nonce to my code so it works?**

especially in the code line if you change the mode and add nonce:

```
cipher = AES.new(self.key, AES.MODE_OCB, iv, nonce=None)
```

**Thanks in advance for any help!**

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are trying to pass a 16 byte nonce.
However, the OCB mode (which is much better than CBC, nice choice!) only works with 15 bytes nonces (at most), so you need to have, at the encryption end:

```
iv = Random.get_random_bytes(15)
```

And at the receiver end:

```
iv = encoded[:15]
```

See also the example [here](https://www.pycryptodome.org/en/latest/src/cipher/modern.html#ocb-mode).

Additionally, your code contains two security errors:

- You derived the AES key with SHA256. Instead, you should run your passwords through a stretching function like PBKDF2 with an appropriate number of iterations, and use its output as key.
- You don't send nor verify the authentication tag, therefore not making usage of the main feature of OCB compared to CBC (i.e. being an [AEAD mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Authenticated_encryption#Authenticated_encryption_with_associated_data)). You should replace `encrypt` with `encrypt_and_digest`, deliver the resulting tag (as athird item, in addition to nonce and ciphertext), and replace `decrypt` with `decrypt_and_verify`).

As a last note, with OCB you don't need any padding, unlike CBC.